# ObservableCollection method add() blocking

Tags: c#, wpf

I working on a project(C# & WPF) where some servers are added to a listbox this way:

```
ObservableCollection<ServerObjects> servers;
ServerObjects so = getServers();
servers->add(so);
```

My problem is that this function is blocking and while items are added to my listbox, I can't select any only after the generating is done(also the program frezes).

So any idee what should I do to make this function asynk?

Thanks.

Comment: "servers->" ? do you use unsafe code?

Comment: @ Tigran: what do you mean by unsafe code ?

Comment: I mean how did you get "->" pointer access in C#?

Comment: Well let me show you the real declaration(its also done in a C++ file): gcroot<ObservableCollection<ServerObjects^>^> myList;

Comment: soo your using C++/CLI not C#? Are you sure thats what you want to use?

Comment: What does getServices do - does it return a LINQ query that hits a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void addServers(ObservableCollection<ServerObjects> ACollection)
{
    //For Common szenarios dont use new Thread() use instead ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(..) or  the TaskFactory
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> this.LoadServer());
}

void MyThreadMethod(Object obj)
{
    ServerObjects so = getServers();

    // The invoke is important, because only the UI Thread should update controls or datasources which are bound to a Control
    UIDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=> (obj as ObservableCollection).add(so));
}
```

You can do is also on RX return an IObservable subscribe on TaskScheduler  and observing on Dispatcher.

-> [Threadpool vs.s Creating own Thread](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/threading-using-the-threadpool-vs-creating-your-own-threads/)
-> [Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Comment: When doing multi-threading with WPF collections, it's worth reading Bea's article on the matter. Most things work, but some scenarios are problematic: http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=34

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
void addServers(ObservableCollection<ServerObjects> ACollection)
{
    Thread T = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MyThreadMethod));
    T.Start(ACollection);
}

void MyThreadMethod(Object obj)
{
    ServerObjects so = getServers();
    (obj as ObservableCollection).add(so);
}
```

The loading of the servers is now executed on another thread.

Comment: I assume that this collection is bound to an UI Control. For that its not a good idea to start a thread and add the elements from the non ui threads to the collection because this ends in an occassionally IllegalCrossThreadException.

So you would have to dispatch back on the UI thread when adding the elements to the list.

Also you should create for such szenarios hard Threads. Use ThreadPool oder Task Parallel Library instread